# How to create contour map for wind speed using Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, weather

I am new to using Geoserver and I am trying to create a contour map for wind speed. Is this SLD style correct to solve my problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
        <NamedLayer>
        <Name>isolines</Name>
        <UserStyle>
        <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
                <Title>linee</Title>
                <Abstract>A style that draws a line</Abstract>
                <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
                <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering lines -->
                <FeatureTypeStyle>
                  <Transformation>
                     <ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
                       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                         <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
                       </ogc:Function>
                       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                         <ogc:Literal>interval</ogc:Literal>
                         <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                      </ogc:Function>
                      <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                         <ogc:Literal>smooth</ogc:Literal>
                         <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                      </ogc:Function>
                      <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                         <ogc:Literal>simplify</ogc:Literal>
                         <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
                      </ogc:Function> 
                    </ogc:Function>
                  </Transformation>
                  <Rule>
                    <Name>rule1</Name>
                    <Title>Blue Line</Title>
                    <Abstract>A solid blue line with a 1 pixel width</Abstract>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                      <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
                      </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                      <Label>
                        <ogc:Function name="round">
                          <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </ogc:Function>
                      </Label>
                      <Font>
                        <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
                      </Font>
                      <LabelPlacement>
                        <LinePlacement/>
                      </LabelPlacement>
                      <Halo>
                        <Radius>
                          <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                        </Radius>
                        <Fill>
                          <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                      </Halo>
                      <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                      </Fill>
                      <Priority>2000</Priority>
                      <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
                      <VendorOption name="repeat">100</VendorOption>
                      <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
                      <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                  </Rule>
                </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
        </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what seems not to be working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use QGIS to create SLD. I think especially for the beginners it is the easiest way.

[image]

[image]

Generally the ".sld" files created by QGIS will work with GeoServer very well, (if the style or labels are not very complicated).

If you want create ".sld" file own by you, you can find examples there:
https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/styling/sld/index.html

If you can send the data example and describe your need more specific way, maybe I can help you more.

Comment: Thank you, I will try using qgis first to create the style.

Comment: QGIS styles not working in GeoServer, is not an issue of complication, it's about using non-standard elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use QGIS to create your map and style it, then use the GeoCAT Bridge plugin to send your layer to Geoserver with the style without having to do additional saving. It works fine so far.

Install Geocat Bridge from the plugin in repository.

[image]

Access it from the Web menu

[image]

Set your Geoserver credentials/settings

[image]

Select the layers you want to publish

[image]

Publishing is successful

[image]

Preview your layer in Geoserver

[image]

You can do the same with your wind speed data.